# ¿Se puede usar el block de notas para programar en Java?

Tags: java, windows

Estoy bastante acostumbrado a programar con *Eclipse*, pero escuché que también se puede usando tan solo el *block de notas* de Windows, me gustaría saber que procedimientos tengo que seguir para compilar e interpretar un programa *java* usando el bloc de notas, claro bajo Windows.

Comment: Por ejemplo: http://gl-epn-programacion-ii.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/como-ejecutar-java-desde-la-consola-cmd.html

Comment: La pregunta no es de Java si no de cómo trabajar con archivos de texto en el Bloc de Notas de Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como el bloc de notas es un editor de texto únicamente, lo que puedes hacer es guardar con terminación ".java", y después compilar por consola como muestra el link que pusiste, esa es la única forma ya que el bloc de notas por si solo no tiene para ejecutar la línea de comando que sirve para ejecutar el compilador de java.